# Mondo-DB Grouping based on two subdocuments

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am trying to write an aggregate query to filter two subdocuments and group them but i can't seem to figure out how to do it with a single query, whether it is possible or not. I have tried a few aggregates and mapReduce queries but couldn't make them work.

Here is an example document:

```
[
    {
        id: "first user",
        read: [{
                    "id" : 'A',
                    free: true
                },
                {
                    "id" : 'B',
                    free: false
                },
                {
                    "id" : 'C',
                    free: true
                }],
        saved: [{
                    "id" : 'B',
                    free: true
                },
                {
                    "id" : 'C',
                    free: false
                }]
    },
    {
        id: "second user",
        read: [{
                    "id" : 'B',
                    free: true
                },
                {
                    "id" : 'C',
                    free: true
                }],
        saved: [{
                    "id" : 'A',
                    free: true
                }]
    }
]
```

Basically, I want to group read and saved subdocuments separately across users while filtering out the non-free ones. Here is the desired ourput:

```
[
    { 
        id: 'A',
        freeRead: [ 'first user'],
        freeSaved: ['second user']
    },
    { 
        id: 'B',
        freeRead: [ 'second user'],
        freeSaved: ['first user']
    },
    { 
        id: 'C',
        freeRead: ['first user', 'second user'],
        freeSaved: []
    }
]
```

Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you are working with distinct values in each of your array results this is not a problem:

```js
db.subs.aggregate([
    // Match valid documents only
    { "$match": {
        "$or": [
            { "read.free": true },
            { "saved.free": true }
        ]
    }},

    // Unwind arrays
    { "$unwind": "$read" },
    { "$unwind": "$saved" },

    // Add type array and unwind
    { "$project": {
        "_id": 0,
        "id": 1,
        "read": 1,
        "saved": 1,
        "type": { "$literal": [ "read", "saved" ] }
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$type" },


    // Group distinct values conditionally by "type"
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "_id": { "$cond": [
                { "$eq": [ "$type", "read" ] },
                { "id": "$read.id", "free": "$read.free" },
                { "id": "$saved.id", "free": "$saved.free" }
            ]},
            "id": "$id",
            "type": "$type"
        }
    }},

    // Only interested in free true
    { "$match": { "_id._id.free": true } },

    // Group conditionally, one document two array fields
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id._id.id",
        "freeRead": { "$addToSet": { "$cond": [
            { "$eq": [ "$_id.type", "read" ] },
            "$_id.id",
            false
        ]}},
        "freeSaved": { "$addToSet": { "$cond": [
            { "$eq": [ "$_id.type", "saved" ] },
            "$_id.id",
            false             
        ]}}
    }},

    // Filter the `false` values
    { "$project": {
        "freeRead": { "$setDifference": [ "$freeRead", [false] ] },
        "freeSaved": { "$setDifference": [ "$freeSaved", [false] ] }
    }},

    // Sort in order
    { "$sort": { "_id": 1 } }
])
```

The generally idea is to alter the structure so that both the "free" and "saved"  results are moved into their own documents marked by what "type" they are. Then while grouping back to the desired `_id` you conditionally select which items to add to either array by "type" using [**`$cond`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/), alternately selecting a value of `false`.

The only thing left then is to "filter" the `false` values out of the array. This is best done using [**`$setDifference`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/) in modern versions but can also be done with careful use of [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) and [**`$match`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/).

You might want to consider storing this data in a more flattened form by "type" as that is what most of the work in this pipeline is doing. From that place the last four pipeline stages are fairly straightforward.